# Assigning data to a socket

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm working with Socket.io, node.js, and express to make a simple two player game that can be played online. Everything I've found on the subject so far either doesn't address my question or is far more complex than what I'm after.

Essentially, I want players to be able to join a room (which I have solved already), and when in a room, need to assign "player 1" and "player 2" attributes to each player. I imagine assigning player 1 to the first connected user and player 2 to the second, but I haven't figured out exactly how to do the assignment of values/variables to an individual socket connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can add attributes to individual sockets like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.name = 'John';
    console.log(socket.name); // prints out 'John'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're looking for should be pretty straightforward.  I like @iheartramen's answer, except it makes it difficult to determine what sockets belong to what room.  What I would do is keep a list of rooms, and what sockets belong to them:

```
var _rooms = [
  {
    id: 'Some Unique Room ID',
    playerSockets: []
  }
  //...
}
```

Then when a player connects to a given room, you just add their connection to the list:

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    var room = getRoom();   // however it is you're mapping rooms...
                            // this returns a reference to a room object
                            // in the _rooms array
    // you can cap the number of players here
    socket.playerNumber = room.sockets.length+1;
    room.sockets.push( socket );
}
```

And now you have backwards and forward mapping.  You don't have to worry about thread safety with the `push()` method because there's only a single event thread.